# How do I index the 3 highest values in a list?

Tags: python

so i have these 2 lists:

```
score = [350, 914, 569, 223, 947, 284, 567, 333, 697, 245, 227, 785, 120, 794, 343, 773, 293, 995]
name = [Ryan, Stacy, Jenna, Peter, Sophie, Bryan, Cole, Andrea, Emily, Blake, Mike, Stephan, Rob, Eliza, Heather, Daniel, Elisabeth, Samantha]
```

I have to find the 3 highest scores and tally these scores with their respective scorers in the name list, so that I can have new lists

```
top3score = [947, 995, 914]
top3name = [Sophie, Samantha, Stacy]
```

I'm thinking of indexing the highest scores, appending them into a list than using the index to tally these scores with the names.

my question is how do i index the 3 highest values in the list?
and then, how do i use the index to look for the scorers name in the name list so that i can append them in the top3name list?

Comment: Wrong data structure. You should be using something like a `dict`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think this will do it

```
sorted(zip(score, name), reverse=True)[:3]
```

So you understand what is going on:

[zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip): takes iterables as it's arguments and takes one element from each iterable, placing them in a tuple.

So:

```
>>> zip(score, name)
[(350, 'Ryan'), (914, 'Stacy'), (569, 'Jenna'), (223, 'Peter'), (947, 'Sophie'), (284, 'Bryan'), (567, 'Cole'), (333, 'Andrea'), (697, 'Emily'), (245, 'Blake'), (227, 'Mike'), (785, 'Stephan'), (120, 'Rob'), (794, 'Eliza'), (343, 'Heather'), (773, 'Daniel'), (293, 'Elisabeth'), (995, 'Samantha')]
```

[sorted](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted): will sort the data.  By default, a tuple element is sorted on the element in the 0 index, so the score in this case.  Reverse=True will sort it descending first.

And lastly, the `[:3]` is slice notation, saying give me all elements from the beginning up to the 3rd element.  This could have also been written as `[0:3]`

Comment: Although simple, sorting is probably more expensive than other solutions as you have probably to iterate the list more than once. In addtion, also store all the intermediate values.

Answer (score 30):

If you're only interested on the top 3, there's[`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, zip(score, name))
[(995, 'Samantha'), (947, 'Sophie'), (914, 'Stacy')]
```

From the [official doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

> `heapq.nlargest(n, iterable, key=None)`
>
> > Return a list with the n largest elements from the dataset defined by iterable. key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the iterable: `key=str.lower` Equivalent to: `sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]`

**Performance notice:**

> The latter two [`nlargest` and `nsmallest`] perform best for smaller values of *n*. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the `sorted()` function. Also, when `n==1`, it is more efficient to use the built-in `min()` and `max()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to get **the indices** instead of **the corresponding elements** in another list, I made a function to sort the indices by list values.

```py
def sort_index(lst, rev=True):
    index = range(len(lst))
    s = sorted(index, reverse=rev, key=lambda i: lst[i])
    return s
```

### Output

Let's try sorting the indices of a sample list.

```py
>>> score = [12, 48, 100, 9, 30]
>>> sort_index(score)
[2, 1, 4, 0, 3]
```

If you want to get the indices of the three largest values, you can just slice the list.

```py
>>> sort_index(score)[:3]
[2, 1, 4]
```

---

It also supports sorting from smallest to largest by using the parameter `rev=False`.

```py
>>> sort_index(score, rev=False)
[3, 0, 4, 1, 2]
```