# An optimal Pythonic way of clipping data by doing some operations per hour for yearly data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data for one day which looks like this:

df =

[image]

And my output should look like this:

[image]

I need to do two main operations:

a)Creating the MDGS:

1. For each individual day I find: abs(GHI_clearsky-GHI) and save it to a pandas series object
2. I then sort this series in descending order.
3. In df['top3_MDGS'] I save the sum of the highest 3 values of the series
4. In df['top1_MDGS'] I save the maximum value of the series

b) Filtering:

5. For each day I go hour by hour and only select the minutes in the hour data which have 60 readings and the df[‘GHI’] values are non –zero
6. If it passes the above condition I only save those results for further analysis other wise it is discarded.

My code used is shown below:

```
def zenith_clipping_MDGS(df):
    data_file = df
    df_zenith_clipped = data_file[data_file.zenith<=86.273]
    df_zenith_clipped.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
    df_zenith_clipped['Hour'] = df_zenith_clipped['Datetime'].dt.hour
    df_zenith_clipped['Date'] = df_zenith_clipped['Datetime'].dt.date
    adj_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for date in df_zenith_clipped.Date.unique():
        print(date)
        df = df_zenith_clipped[df_zenith_clipped.Date == date]
        MDGS = abs(df.GHI_clearsky - df.GHI)
        MDGS = MDGS.sort_values(ascending = False)
        MDGS.reset_index(inplace = True, drop=True)
        df['top3_MDGS'] = sum(MDGS[:3])
        df['top1_MDGS'] = MDGS[0]

        for hour in df.Hour.unique():
            df1 = df[df.Hour == hour]
            if (len(df1) == 60) and (df1.GHI.any() != 0):
                adj_df = adj_df.append(df1)
            else:
                continue
    adj_df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop=True)
    
    return adj_df
```

This is actually taking more time than it should. Are there some functions, or a better way to go about this?

Thanks,
Appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that could possibly be optimized...

a) If you only need the top 3 values in the series, it may not be very efficient to sort the entire list for those values, as additional operations will be expended on redundant sorting. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152131/how-do-i-index-the-3-highest-values-in-a-list) discuss some more efficient methods (for example, using `max()` to find the highest value, removing it from the list, and repeating 3 times).

b) Although I'm not entirely familiar with the data/frameworks you're using, it looks like you might be able to optimize the hour lookup - particularly with the `df1 = df[df.Hour == hour]`, it seems that the `==` would need to iterate through everything in `df.Hour` just to find the one matching element. If this could be rewritten to use a numerical index without needing to search, it might execute faster.

Comment: I think my main problem to solve is my second part, where I filter. That is taking up a lot of time.